# Selenium-extract WebDriver from jar for execution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium program that is intended to be copied onto other computers before execution. I would like to only have to ship out a runnable jar. On execution the program should extract chromdriver.exe to a new directory in the directory from which the program was executed. The .exe should only be exported if it does not already exist in that exact location. Assuming I do already know the .exe is not there, how do I program the application to extract the .exe File? The resource folder has been added to the class path under sources (I am using eclipse) so the .exe does appear in the jar when I export the project. Now I just need to see how to extract it on execution

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide some code samples?  Particularly any attempts you have made towards this problem with your best guess as to why it may have failed.  By doing this you'll greatly increase your chances of someone going out of their way to provide a detailed answer to help you.  Showing that you've first put your best effort in will net you a much more positive response among the community.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your chromedriver.exe file is contained in your jar file in a package named res. The following code will extract the file to your local harddrive.

```
        InputStream i = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/chromedriver.exe");
        Files.copy(i, new File("c:\\target\\chromedriver.exe").toPath());
```

You can add a CopyOption if you like.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you!